# php error checking mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date, casting

caveat: i am new to php

I'm reading in 2 dates from a form in a mysql format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) and trying to error check them both for validity and that one is less than the other

```
if(!empty($day1) && !empty($day2)){
 $sndate=array();
 $sndate = explode('-',$day1);
 $sndtnum = implode($sndate);
 $sndtnum = (int) $sndtnum;

 $unsndate=array();
 $unsndate = explode('-',$day2);
 $unsndtnum = implode($unsndate);
 $unsndtnum = (int) $unsndtnum;
  if (!checkdate($sndate[1],$sndate[2],sndate[0]) || !checkdate($unsndate[1],$unsndate[2],unsndate[0]) || $unsndtnum<$sndtnum)
  { $error=True; $errtext .="Date field is filled in wrong \n";
  }else {$error=False;}
}
```

This does not seem to work. I'm pretty sure it's because of the checkdate, but i'm not positive that there isn't also an issue with the implode/cast.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Why not simply convert the $day1 and $day2 values to [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), then compare the resulting objects?

Comment: I was missing the $ from the $unsndate[0] and $sndate[0].  sorry for wasting people's time, but please feel free to reuse the code. @Mark , i personally think this is easier.

Comment: MarkBaker is right. You can get difference by using strtotime() also...

Comment: yeah....agreed with you.

Comment: Easier than 8 lines of code?!?

Comment: +1 Dhruv. I was thinking the exact same. Also, DateTime would do it too, but it takes a few more lines of code to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `sndate[0]` and `unsndate[0]` variables missing their dollar signs, your check will actually not work if an evil user put non-numeric chars in `$day1` (e.g. `2015-09abc-01` will be considered as less than `2015-05-01`).

The following approach validates the dates by transforming them from a known format into a DateTime object and then back again, making sure that the two formatted dates are equal:

```
$f = 'Y-m-d';
$ok1 = ($d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($f, $day1)) && $d1->format($f) == $day1;
$ok2 = ($d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($f, $day2)) && $d2->format($f) == $day2;

if ($ok1 && $ok2 && $d1 <= $d2) {
    // Ok
} else {
    // Error
}
```

Hope this helps :)